# My props in NextJS keep returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, contentful

I'm trying to setup a connection with Contentful. The connection seems to work and isn't the problem, but once I try to transfer the data via the props I keep getting 'undefined'.

I've stripped down the code to the core issue since this also returns undefined.

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Index(props) {
  console.log(props.heading);
  return (
    <div>Projects</div>
  )
}
export function getStaticProps() {
  return {
    props: {
      heading: "test"
    },
  }
}
```

I hope one of you can explain whats happening. I'm not an expert in NextJS but I have 10 years of expierence in PHP, I usually understand whats happening or can atleast reverse engineer a problem.

Comment: No Its working fine the value of console.log inside Index comp is coming 'test' not undefined.

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal not for me. I get: ```- event compiled successfully in 622 ms (565 modules)
undefined ```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the getStaticProps() function is executed at building of the project. So if you run

```
npm run build
```

After the project is successfully build, run the

```
npm start
```

and the console logging of the props.heading will be outputted.